# Site Global Product Search with HikaShop

Tags: hikashop

I realize there are filter modules in the HikaShop extension - and they're almost what I'm looking for.

However, I can't figure out how to apply those filters **not** to the currently opened category but rather on all existing categories so that the results are a mixture from all categories where there have been results found.

What am I missing here? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your HikaShop Filter module settings, that you can find when you edit the module via the Joomla modules manager, you can turn on the "force redirect" setting.
Then, when the customer uses the filters in the module, instead of staying on the current listing of products and filter these products, it will redirect the search to the products listing menu item for which you entered the id in the "menu" setting of the filter module.